# A responsive responsive-square in pure CSS positioned to the top right of a div element of any size - possible?

Tags: html, css, gradient

So here is what I am trying to accomplish...

I want to place a perfect square that always covers one or possibly both corners without ever going over in the top right corner of a div... no matter the size or dimensions of the div in question that requires the gradient corner effect.

The reason I want to do that is so I can add gradient effects to corners of sections of a website as so many designers are asking me to do.

The simplest way to do it would be with a transparent PNG file of the gradient obviously... and just set it's height, width, max-height, and max-width to 100% and pin it to the top right of the div in question.

I am too stubborn, though!

This should be possible with pure CSS!

I just can't seem to figure out how.

I have tried nesting multiple responsive square divs and rotating them but to no avail.

I think I am just too tired, and will hopefully be able to answer my own question in the morning!

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can use psedu element :after or :before

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute logic in CSS.

Try with this concept.

```css
.container {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.corner-element {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="corner-element"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

</div>
```